Choppy/crackling audio
Having this issue for half a year, from 23.10 to 24.04. Audio would crackle, pop, and be overall choppy whenever sounds are played. Doesn't matter from what software; firefox, vlc, mocp. All the same.
Over time, I started noticing a trend. The issue would be incredibly bad if I were to play sounds immediately after logging in. However, if the computer has been not played a sound since being turned on, and is left to either idle, or I do anything that doesn't involve the computer playing any sounds for at least 10 minutes (arbitrary guess), any sound played thereafter is almost perfect.
This time variable stumps me. Regardless, tried different cables, HDMI ports, TVs, kernels, drivers (amdgpu vs kisak PPA), X11 vs Wayland, Pipewire vs ALSA, the tsched trick, and the default-sample-rate trick, making sure that only one troubleshooting attempt is made before reverting and trying the next trick.
I'm out of ideas.

My Ubuntu only has crackling issues when playing music.
According to shaunob1's reply in this post. You can try to set the clock.force-rate to 44100.
pw-metadata -n settings 0 clock.force-rate 44100

This command obviously alleviated my problem, but it did not completely solve it.
